# How to get the correct userID in my sql query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I have the following query in my Node application:

```
select
  *
from
  messengerList
where
  messenger_id = ${u_id}
  and not status = "rejected"
  or messenged_id = ${u_id}
  and not status = "rejected"
```

it looks as follows in the function

```
let chatIdList = await sqlSrv.getSqlResults(`select * from messengerList where messenger_id=${u_id} and not status="rejected" or messenged_id=${u_id} and not status="rejected"`)
    .catch(error => {throw error});
```

I don't want to select all, I just want to select the `id` and the `messenger_id` or `messenged_id` where the id is not equal to `u_id`.
So, `chatIdList` should look like this:

```
[{id: 1, messenger_id: 3}, {id: 2, messenged_id: 5}] // messenger_id != messenged_id != u_id
```

Can I achieve this by changing the query? When yes, could you provide such a query or an example?

Comment: You can't return different column names in different rows of a single query.

Comment: You also need to fix the SQL injection vector (let me introduce you to [my friend Bobby](https://bobby-tables.com/)). Use parameterized queries, not (effectively) string concatenation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Hey, thank you and I will!

Answer (score 0):

basically what you did except add another condition to eliminate those that you don't want to show :

```
select
  *
from
  messengerList
where
not status = "rejected"
and messenger_id <> messenged_id
  and (
       messenger_id = ${u_id}
       or messenged_id = ${u_id}
  )
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you did, and why/how it works.

Comment: @Lobster hmm.. then  what is it you are looking for as result , in your question ,paste your data and your desired output

Comment: It still selects both ids and not only the one which is not equal to ```u_id```. I just go in a for loop now and delete the key holding the id equal to ```u_id```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood it correctly.
first, you list all data
then, you make with if query

**simple code**

```
SELECT * FROM messengerList
```

then,

```
  if(res.rows[i].messenger_id==u_id){
          //....
     }else{
          //----
     }
```

Comment: I  thought it could be done by changing the query but I just modify the array after I get the results: ```for(let chat of chatIdList){
         chat.messenger_id == u_id ? delete chat.messenger_id : delete chat.messenged_id;
    } ```